# Removing two words from text from string javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

Hey I'm looking at removing words from a string, thing is the word to replace could be two different words.

e.g.

```
foo = "stringtest";
id = foo.replace('string', '');
```

or

```
foo = "paragraphtest";
id = foo.replace('paragraph', '');
```

at the moment I've approached the problem as so.

```
foo = "paragraphtest";
id = foo.replace('paragraph', '');
id = foo.replace('string', '');
```

I know this code could easily be improve but I don't know how :( thanks for your assistance.

Comment: You're overwriting `id` replacing "string" from the ORIGINAL string, not the string with the first replacement made already. Just chain them `id = foo.replace('paragraph', '').replace('string', '');`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this?

```
var foo = ["paragraph","string"];
var id = foo.replace(new RegExp(foo.join("|"),""));
```

The above creates array with strings you want to replace and joins it with `|` in `RegExp` constructor and replaces the match with empty string.

Comment: You are missing one ). As so: `foo.replace(new RegExp(foo.join("|"),""))`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(foo.indexOf("ph") > -1)
 id = foo.replace('paragraph', '');
else
 id = foo.replace('string', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe. Which will also give you the flexibility to modify what you replace each string with.

```
var replacementCharacters = [
  {
    searchString: "paragraph",
    replacementString: ""
  },
  {
    searchString: "string",
    replacementString: ""
  }
];

function runReplacement(str) {
  var returnValue = str;
  for (var i = 0; i < replacementCharacters.length; i++) {
    returnValue = returnValue.replace(replacementCharacters[i].searchString, replacementCharacters[i].replacementString);
  }
  return returnValue;
}


var foo = "paragraphtest";
var id = runReplacement(foo);
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/RfKt4/